# Java Multiple Button Clicks

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have 5 buttons on the pannel, named "add", "edit", "delete", "ok", "cancel". Now if I click the cancel button straight away, the form terminates. I have called the `dispose()` method from the click event.

However, what I want to do is: if I click the add button first and then click the cancel button, the program should get back to the initial state, in spite of terminating, because of `dispose()`.

How do I do it ?

Here's my add button action event code:

```
public class TheButtounHandler implements ActionListener
{
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
     {
         if(ae.getSource().equals(addButton))
         {
             enableDisabledByDefault();
             editButton.setEnabled(false);
             deleteButtoun.setEnabled(false);
             addButton.setEnabled(false);
             if(ae.getSource().equals(cancelButton))
             {
                 disabledByDefault();
             }
         }
         else if(ae.getSource().equals(cancelButton))
         {
             dispose();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to handle the `cancel` button in the same `if`-branch as the `add` button, by checking `ActionEvent.getSource()`, but this code will never execute since the source can not be both `addButton` and `cancelButton` at the same time.

Instead, you need to move the `disabledByDefault()` call into the part which handles the `cancelButton`, and distinguish there whether `add` has been pressed before, either by adding a new variable (which you set when the `add` button is pressed), or by simply checking the state of the `add` button:

```
...
else if(ae.getSource().equals(cancelButton))
{
    if (!addButton.isEnabled()) {
        disabledByDefault();
    } else {
        dispose();
    }
}
```